# Why does map work differently when I return an array instead of some primitive in the callback function?

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary

Script

```js
var companies=[
{name:'Vicky',category:'Devdas',start:1993,end:2090},
{name:'Vikrant',category:'Devdas',start:1994,end:2019},
{name:'Akriti',category:'mental',start:1991,end:2021},
{name:'Dummy',category:'dummyCategory',start:1995,end:2018},
{name:'Dummy 1',category:'dummyCategory',start:1993,end:2029}
];
var mappingComp=companies.map(company=>{company.start+10;return company});
console.log("mapped company function");
console.log(mappingComp.forEach(company=>console.log(company)));
```

In the above snippet there is no change in start field of companies array . Why ?

In case I do below I do get modified values for start field from companies array.

```
var mappingComp=companies.map(company=>company.start+10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result of `company.start+10` to anything - it's just an orphaned expression.

```
var mappingComp = companies.map(company => {
  company.start + 10;
  return company
});
```

is just like

```
var mappingComp = companies.map(company => {
  33;
  return company
});
```

The expression is evaluated to a value and then discarded. If you want to *add* 10 to `company.start`, use `+=` or `=`:

```js
var companies=[
{name:'Vicky',category:'Devdas',start:1993,end:2090},
{name:'Vikrant',category:'Devdas',start:1994,end:2019},
{name:'Akriti',category:'mental',start:1991,end:2021},
{name:'Dummy',category:'dummyCategory',start:1995,end:2018},
{name:'Dummy 1',category:'dummyCategory',start:1993,end:2029}
];
var mappingComp = companies.map(company => {
  company.start += 10;
  return company;
});
console.log(mappingComp);
```

But this will mutate the original array, which is (often) not a great idea when using `map`. If you don't want to change the original array, `map` to a new object:

```js
var companies=[
{name:'Vicky',category:'Devdas',start:1993,end:2090},
{name:'Vikrant',category:'Devdas',start:1994,end:2019},
{name:'Akriti',category:'mental',start:1991,end:2021},
{name:'Dummy',category:'dummyCategory',start:1995,end:2018},
{name:'Dummy 1',category:'dummyCategory',start:1993,end:2029}
];
var mappingComp = companies.map(({ start, ...rest }) => ({
  start: start + 10,
  ...rest
}));
console.log(mappingComp);
```

Comment: Perfect and Thanks

Answer (score 0):

company.start + 10 is a simple expression. It's not an assignment statement, that you are expecting it to be. And you are returning the initial array company so it makes sense that it will be returned unaltered.

when you tried the single line fat arrow function with the map. What happens is that you created another entirely different array of mutated values. The array created was populated with values (company.start +10) and returned. Note: This actually didn't change the initial array ie company.

Read up on fat arrow functions, map, filter.